# How to get the recent record through GROUP BY clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I have one table `tbl_events` where I have `id(PK), account_id, email, event`. Now each `account_id` have **multiple records** but I want the last/recent record of each `account_id`. My Query is

> SELECT id, account_id, email, event FROM tbl_events GROUP BY(account_id)

I have tried MAX, ORDER BY, JOINS, but all in vain.
One more thing I have records in millions. `event` is the more important entity in my case and the values are `processed`, `delivered`, `open` etc. 
I want to check the last `event` against each `account_id`. Help me please

Comment: joins in one table?

Comment: Can you elaborate how `account_id` has multiple records?

Comment: because one account_id has different events.. As this is for email activities like when processed, when delivered, when opened etc

Answer (score 1):

You could use a inner join the max(id) group by account_id

```
  select e.id, e.account_id, e.email, e.event
  from tbl_events e 
  inner join  (
      select account_id, max(id) max_id
      from tbl_events
      group by account_id

  ) t on t.max_id = e.id and t.account_id = e.account_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.id, T.account_id, T.email, T.event
FROM tbl_events T
JOIN 
   (SELECT MAX(id) as last_id, account_id, email, event
   FROM tbl_events
   GROUP BY account_id) L
ON L.last_id = T.id 
  AND L.account_id = T.account_id
```

Should work. But it's going to be awfully slow with millions of records, because the subselect is not indexed.

The full solution depends on your needs. For occasional reports, create a temporary table with the subselect and index it. If it's an ongoing thing, then you need to cheat first normal rules and add last_id fields to the account table :-)

Comment: "I want the last/recent record of each account_id."  The values for email and event could vary and not actually relate to the max(ID) [From Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html), " The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."

Comment: Created an inner join with the actual correct data, much slower but correct
INNER JOIN will not work. You need an actual JOIN

Comment: this will just give me the last/recent id not the whole row.. I want same for event but event is a string type value.

Comment: I edited it to give you what you want. You need a "JOIN" and not an "INNER JOIN"

Comment: yes, that is much slower because I have records in millions. Anyways thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the latest event will have the highest ID, which will be the case in most cases:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT account_id, MAX(id) AS 'id' FROM tbl_events GROUP BY account_id
) AS t1 
INNER JOIN tbl_events t2 ON (t1.account_id = t2.account_id AND t1.id = t2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply max(event) in your select query.

Comment: I don't think this will work, because event is string value (varchar)